# Connectivity of netbeans to java

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I'm not able to insert values in netbeans (see code below)

Please tell me what is the error.

Here my database name is "pulkit"and table name is "studinfo".

and ...my error is, as I insert values there should be double inverted columns(" ")to insert words in netbeans while coding...but netbeans is giving error, as you can see below

Here is the code:

ALL IMPORTS THAT I TYPED IN NETBEANS :-

```
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.Statement;
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

In generated code:

```
Connection con=null;
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pulkit";
String  usr="root";
String pwd="a";
String  dr="java.sql.driver";
String  qry="";
Statement stmt=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
```

Now in button code:-

```
   try{
       Class.forName(dr);
       con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr, pwd);
      **\\Error qry=("insert into studinfo values(2,"ram","XII-sci")";\\**
       stmt=con.createStatement();
       stmt.executeUpdate(url);
       rs=stmt.executeQuery(url);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"saved..record");
     }   catch ( Exception e )   {

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( rootPane, " sorry.....  " ) ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've committed series of errors in the code. I would recommend you to learn the syntax first from a credible source.

**1) Error in Query statement**

`String qry=("insert into studinfo values(2,"ram","XII-sci")";`

Errors:
 1. In order to store String values in database, you need to use single quotes and not double quotes.
 2. You need to put semi-colon at the end of the sql query.

Correct syntax:
`String qry="insert into studinfo values(2,'ram','XII-sci');";`

If you want to store String values using variables use,

`String qry="insert into studinfo values(2,'"+Variable1+"','"+Variable2+"');";`

**2) Error in ExecuteQuery**

`rs=stmt.executeQuery(url);`

The `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pulkit";` is for connection to the database. You don't pass it as a parameter to `executeQuery()`. You're supposed to pass `String qry="insert into studinfo values(2,'"+Variable1+"','"+Variable2+"');";` as the parameter to `executeQuery()`

Your final code should be:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

Connection con=null;
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pulkit";
String  usr="root";
String pwd="a";
String  dr="java.sql.driver";
String  qry="";
Statement stmt=null;
int rs=null;

try{
    Class.forName(dr);
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr, pwd);
    String qry="insert into studinfo values(2,'ram','XII-sci');";
    stmt=con.createStatement();    
    rs=stmt.executeQuery(qry);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"saved..record");
}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( rootPane, " sorry.....  " ) ;
}
```